# Why can't I use the jQuery Tooltip Plugin on a TR?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

I can't use this on a TR, specifically my selector is:

```
$(".alignment_tr  td:not('.remove-link')")
```

Comment: let's see some html to go with that selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean in your question. TR elements can have events attached to them, so there is theoretically no obstacle to have tooltips attached on them.

Your selector selects `td` elements. If you want the `tr` associated, just call `.parent()`.

Alternatively, use `:has()` :

```
$(".alignment_tr:has(td:not('.remove-link'))")
```